# Adding tag to question in order to describe accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, tags

If a person asks a question and they state they don't have a preference for how the solution is provided (ex: ModelBuilder or ArcPy), but they would gladly accept either one.

In this scenario, if an ArcPy solution is given, and the answer is accepted, is it okay to add [arcpy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcpy) as a tag to the question afterward?

Comment: +1 for asking, despite I have a different opinion on this matter.

Comment: If there are tag slots available I see no harm in adding them. I think the better question might be how appropriate is it to retrofit questions to answers - if they accept the arcpy answer, do you remove the modelbuilder tag and references in the question? Sometimes this has been done, particularly in cases where the other route is already answered at another question. In theory both tags should have already been on the question *prior* to the answer. If a question provides too many avenues for solution, it falls under the 'too broad' category and is up for closure.

Comment: And what if the answer hasn't been marked as accepted but the answer seems to be valid according to the community? And probably it won't be because the question was posted one and a half years ago.  For example: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82892/how-to-copy-the-color-styling-to-a-color-column-in-a-layers-attribute-table/155429 Should I add a [tag:PyGIS] tag? @polygeo

Comment: @gcarrillo Definitely, because the Q&A which has evolved from the original question now has a large `pyqgis` component.  The original asker has the option to accept (or not) an answer, but I think the community owns how Q&As are tagged.  I think this matches what I have said in my [answer](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3992).

Answer (score 3):

I would certainly encourage you to add such tags because doing so will better summarize the content of that Q&A.

The lasting record of what we do here is the latest state the Question & Answer(s) rather than just the original Question, and so anything that helps describe it accurately, both in terms of tags and the title, will help it be found by those in future need.

However, when reviewing tags I would also take into account the content of any highly upvoted answers not just the accepted one.

Answer (score 3):

I would not do it; keep the question focused on the problem rather than the software. A better answer from a different platform can come in the future.

Otherwise, we will flood the system with similar questions, when we could have few posts with a full repository on a problem or task. It is ok to ask about a specific software, but the demand should come from the OP, not from the community trying to fit every question to a software.

An accepted answer on such questions means that an alternative solved the OP's problem, but it is not describing the question demanded software 'x'.

---

Found the below related post:

[Should I add a tag to a question, if it's associated with the marked answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149345/should-i-add-a-tag-to-a-question-if-its-associated-with-the-marked-answer/149347#149347)

by Bill the Lizard:

> In general, it depends. Would adding the tag exclude other possible answers that don't include the subject of the tag? If so, then don't add it.

I think this is the case here. Labeling a question with software 'x' when the OP clearly did not demand software 'x', will exclude other possible solutions with software 'y', 'z', etc.

Comment: I think `Bill the Lizard` may be in the minority with that comment because that Meta SE Q&A is a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26913/should-i-retag-a-question-with-a-tag-that-is-based-on-the-answer-and-not-the-que which says very strongly the opposite.  I recommend this answer from `random`: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/26914

Comment: That post mentions an example where the OP tagged a question with mysql and an editor added other complementary and broader conceptual tags (sql, count, group-by) based on answers. Here is the opposite. (cc/ @PolyGeo)

Comment: I agree that there are differences in the two situations as you have pointed out but I think consensus is found in a principle that it is the Q&A being tagged rather than just the Q.